# Error installing matplotlib for Python 3: "Python 3.1. required which was not found in registry"

Tags: python, installation, python-3.x, registry, matplotlib

I downloaded matplotlib [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib). I'm running Windows 7 and have python in a folder C:\Python31.

Answer (score 2):

Python 3 support for Matplotlib is still pretty experimental (it's not even yet mentioned on the [installation page](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/installing.html)), but you can try anyway by downloading the source from [Github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib-py3) and trying:

```
C:\Python31\python.exe setup.py install
```

Comment: The binary installer for matplotlib that I downloaded was explicitly labeled for Python 3. (see [link] (http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib))

Comment: You're right, sorry. Have you tried downloading the source and installing that way?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a 64-bit version of Python installed, make sure you are installing the 64-bit version of matplotlib (win-amd64), not the 32-bit (win32) version of matplotlib, and vice-versa.